# Can we apply L'hopital Rule when we have $\frac{-\infty}{+\infty}$?

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I saw in a book, it evaluated $\lim_{x\to0^+}\cfrac{(\ln x)^3}{\frac1x}$  with L'hopital Rule. the fraction is $\frac{-\infty}{+\infty}$ actually. so can I use L'hopital rule safely every time I see something like $\frac{-\infty}{+\infty}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. That's so because, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$, then\begin{align}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}&=-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{-f(x)}{g(x)}\\&=-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(-f)'(x)}{g'(x)}\\&=-\lim_{x\to a}\frac{-f'(x)}{g'(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Write

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{f(x)}}$$

to transform $ \frac{\infty}{\infty} $ into $ \frac 00$.

Comment: This is a very good trick!

Comment: I use often this method :-)....

Comment: @Sebastiano You are Welcome. Baggio and Pirlo.

Comment: I was a boy when Baggio scored that famous goal at USA 1994 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yf2lJprAc58
Pirlo is a very good player, but he is a Juventus man, or rather a "rubentino" (i.e. a Juventus man who steals badges and games) ahahahah.

Comment: @Sebastiano Del Piero was also a good player.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Even if you are from Juventus I vote you the same ahahahah.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am from Morocco. We love Italian Football. Good Night Italy.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes yes...I know for your name :-)...all the best and good night...

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks a lot . Best Wishes .

Comment: If I may ask, where are you located ? I asked this question because my family arrived there in 1912. My parents were born there, I was born thers, my wife too. I made my studies in Rabat and I statred my carreer at the university of Rabat in 1961. It is more our country than any other place in the world. Cheers *SaaHebi*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Bonjour. Ssalam. Je suis de Meknès. Mes respects et meilleurs vœux.